# What is the significance of Planck's constant in De Broglie–Bohm theory or Pilot-wave theory?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-interpretations, physical-constants

In standard QM, Planck's constant seems to be a constant that describes the smallest quanta of energy in some way. Does De Broglie–Bohm theory have an alternate interpretation of that constant and what it means about space-time or particles (or both)?

Comment: it probably doesn't need to be said, but I'll do it anyway so no one else has to do it: as far as we know, there is no such thing as a smallest quantum of energy

Answer (score 2):

Bohm's interpretation of the QM says that a particle moves along a trajectory, as in the classical mechanics, however, the potential in which this particle moves is supplemented by a "quantum potential". In all the equation of movement relevant for this question is

(1) $\frac {∂S}{∂t} + \frac {(\nabla S)^2}{2m} + \left[V(x) - \frac {\hbar ^2}{8m} \left(2\frac {\Delta P}{P} - \frac {(\nabla P)^2}{P^2} \right) \right] = 0$,

where $S$ and $P$ are defined by expressing the wave-function as

(2) $\psi = P \ e^{iS/ \hbar}$.

Here is what Bohm says about the constant $\hbar$ :

" *... in the classical limit* $\hbar \to 0$ *the above equations
are subject to a very simple interpretation. The function
$S(x)$ is a solution of the Hamilton-Jacobi equation.*"

However, as long as the limit $\hbar \to 0$ doesn't hold, the trajectory of a particle is influenced, besides $V(x)$, by a "*quantum potential*" generated by the wave-function,

$V^{quantum} = -\frac {\hbar ^2}{8m} \left(2\frac {\Delta P}{P} - \frac {(\nabla P)^2}{P^2} \right)$.

Thus, the magnitude of $\hbar$ relative to the considered problem **separates between the classical and quantum behavior**.

Comment: Interesting. I'd like to understand your bolded point more concretely. The units of h are energy multiplied over a distance. Can you add some interpretation of those units in this context?

Comment: @BT , no $\hbar $ has dimensions of energy multiplied by *time*. $\hbar$ is *action*. The relevance of this quantity is inherited from classical mechanics - from the principle of least action, which says that a particle follows in space the trajectory on which the action is *minimal*. And what is that action? the Lagrangian (that has dimensions of energy) multiplied by time.

Comment: Ah right, I misspoke. So the ℏ has units of *action*. Didn't realize that was a type of unit. Sounds like you're saying that by using 0 as the value for h, we basically get classical mechanics, and that h is the value that is required to describe the "quantum potential". Could you elaborate on what the quantum potential is, and what ℏ means to it? Perhaps ℏ relates to how much mass is necessary to generate a given frequency and/or amplitude of particles' waves (purely speculating here)?

Comment: @BT : you ask me too many things at once. Please, one step at one time. What $\hbar $ means to the quantum potential you saw in my answer: let $\hbar \to 0$, and we have classical mechanics. But, worse that that : the uncertainty principle says $\Delta x \Delta p_x \ge \hbar/2 $. But if $\hbar \to 0$, there is no interdiction to have $\Delta x \Delta p_x = 0$. So, no uncertainty principle - classical mechanics. Well, about quantum potential can you post a question? In the space of the comments it's difficult to answer. The quantum potential tells the particle where it can be and where not.

Comment: @BT : do you remember the 2slit experiment? Well, the quantum potential doesn't allow the Bohmian trajectories to pass through the forbidden fringes.

Comment: Ah I see, the quantum potential is the wave described by schrodinger's equation, and drives the path of a sub-atomic particle. I do know the double-slit experiment. I understand what you're saying that the significance of ℏ is that it defines how precisely we can measure. But I'm wondering if it also has significance as far as how the quantum potential forms (frequencies/amplitudes).

Comment: @BT you ask "But I'm wondering if it also has significance as far as how the quantum potential forms (frequencies/amplitudes)." Can you formulate your question more clearly? Frequencies and amplitudes belong to the wave function. No, I don't think that I understand your question.

Comment: Your explanation makes me think that at ℏ there is no quantum potential (no wave), and so the higher the ℏ, the greater the amplitude the quantum potential would have for a given particle. Is this correct? Does it have a similar relationship with the frequency of such waves?

Comment: @BT *at ℏ there is no quantum potential (no wave)*; not at $\hbar$ but at $\hbar \to 0$. About frequency, please describe how do you think that the relation can look like. I guess that you have some imagine in your mind. Tell me what is it and I'll tell you if it can hold.

Comment: @BT but, take into account that in my country it's already bed-time, so try to answer quickly.

Comment: @BT - let's leave it for tomorrow I go to sleep.

Comment: Oops, i mistyped, yes I meant at ℏ == 0. About amplitude, I would say the larger ℏ is, the larger the amplitudes of wave functions of particles. Is that correct? For frequency, I have no idea. And I appreciate all your answers, but there's no rush for me to get them. Get some rest ; )